# What's the effect in Ruby when you initialize with nil: x = String(nil)

Tags: ruby, initialization, null

What's the effect in Ruby when you pass `nil` to the constructor as in:

```
s = String(nil)
```

or

```
a = Array(nil)
```

Does this mean that `s` or `a` **is** `nil` or that `s` or `a` is an unpopulated object of type `String` or type `Array`?

Comment: ugh, why didn't you just try it??! what's wrong with you?

`s = String(nil); puts s.class`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String(arg)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005966) calls `to_s` on `arg` and returns the result. [`nil.to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/NilClass.html#M001174) returns a new empty string. `String(nil)` therefore returns a new empty string.

[`Array(arg)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005967) attempts to call `to_ary` and then `to_a` on `arg`, returning the result of the first method that exists (or `[arg]` if neither method exists). [`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/NilClass.html) doesn't have a `to_ary` method, but [`nil.to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/NilClass.html#M001175) returns a new empty array. `Array(nil)` therefore returns a new empty array.

Note that `String(arg)` and `Array(arg)` aren't constructors. They are just global methods defined in [`Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html). To construct objects in Ruby, you typically call `new` on a class, e.g. [`Array.new(2)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002150) to create an array of length 2.